# Issues with Swing timers

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have 3 timers running on my application which takes care of different action. Timer 1 will deals with automatic logout of the application, timer 2 deals with updating a table, timer 3 deals with updating the color of swing buttons. First timer uses the calculation based on the variables and its values, second and third timers works out of MYSQL queries.

Now when i run this application on an average performance machine the application is not moving .I need to wait for few seconds to a normal click to happen or a window to open. Is it something to do with the timers ? If yes do I have any alternative suggestions to get rid of this timer problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not be related to the Swing timers, that is something else in your code. You need to debug the application to see what is causing the delay.

Comment: so are you sure that the timers will not make the application to freeze ? THe application will be running all the day busy all the time. Is it ok if i run 5 timers at the same time ??

Comment: Are you sure you need so many timers. You could have the same functionality in one just give them different check intervals if a must? Otherwise the answer must be in the code, let us see it.

Comment: @Deepak, if you are doing something that could hold up the EDT then you need to move that off.  To confirm this you need to profile your application.  Running 50 timers at the same time is not a problem as long as you aren't running big tasks on them.

Comment: @jzd: i have attached the snapshot of profiling details of my application. I am new to this and i cant understand what it is doing. help me out plz..

Comment: @Deepak, attached it where?  What you need to do is find out how long the actionPreformed methods take for each of the timers. You can store it in a variable and do a System.out.println().  Find out if they are taking a lot of time to run or not.

Comment: @jzd: open the image in new window to enlarge it. its kinda weird in this display :)

Comment: @Deepak, I am not going to debug your app.  Take a look at my last comment, find out how long it takes the Timers to run to see if that is a problem. If not find out what is happening when you start the application up.

Comment: ok thanks for that. I just figured out how to profile each methods. I am doing it now! thanks for that!!

Answer (score 5):

It could well be the timers, if they are performing considerable work when fired. It's not usually a good idea to use swing timers for long-running tasks, since they will block the EDT and freeze the UI.

Here are some suggestions to avoid this:

1. Use a [java.util.Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) rather than the swing timer. This will run the database code on a background thread, avoiding blocking the event queue.
2. Continue to use the swing timer, but have the timer action simply start a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform the task. This gives the benefit of background processing with the ability to post updates to your UI, if it's a operation that takes more than a second or so to execute.

The problem isn't how many timers you have, but how long each timer takes to do it's work, since the timer's `actionPerformed` method is run on the swing event thread, meaning that while a timer is doing it's thing, no UI updates can happen.

Comment: +1. It must be as @mdma is saying that some of the operations that timers are doing are to lengthy. Reading Java Tutorial about swing Timer: "In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing." http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, swing timers fire events on the same thread used for rendering, so you dont tend to get exceptions due to incorrect thread interractions - I have used them in the past for animations without issue - I suspect the answer lies elsewhere in your code. Have you tried profiling the code at the point where you are having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK if I run 5 timers at the same time?

All instances of [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) "perform their waiting using a single, shared thread." The limit occurs when the tread becomes saturated. As a practical matter, each [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) may have multiple listeners, but "the handlers must execute quickly to keep the GUI responsive."