# Display animation with thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to display many animation at the same time with thread.
But It doesn't work, the second animation start when the first end.
I'm using thread but probably the wrong way because i'm beginner
Here is my code :

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

    Mouse mouse;
    ArrayList<Explosion> explosions;

    public Board() {            
        mouse = new Mouse(this);        
        explosions = new ArrayList();       
        setDoubleBuffered(true);         
        this.addMouseListener(mouse);
    }

    public void addExplosion(Explosion e) {
        explosions.add(e);
        new Thread(explosions.get(explosions.indexOf(e))).start();
    }

    public void removeExplosion(Explosion e) {
        explosions.remove(e);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        for(int i=0; i<explosions.size(); i++) {
            explosions.get(i).paintComponent(g);
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
}


public class Explosion extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private BufferedImage img;

    final int width = 320;
    final int height = 320;
    final int rows = 5;
    final int cols = 5;

    private int x,y;

    private int cursor;

    BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];

    Board board;

    public Explosion(Board board,int x, int y) {
        this.board = board;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        try {
            try {
                this.img = ImageIO.read(new File((this.getClass().getResource("files/explosion2.png")).toURI()));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cursor = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sprites[(i * cols) + j] = img.getSubimage(
                    j * (width/rows),
                    i * (height/cols),
                    width/rows,
                    height/cols
                );
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {     
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
               cursor++;
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, taskPerformer);

        while(cursor < ((rows*cols)-1)) {           
            timer.start();
            board.repaint();                
        }
        timer.stop();

        board.removeExplosion(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(sprites[cursor], x, y, this);
        g.dispose();    
    }   
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but isn't: `explosions.get(explosions.indexOf(e))` equivalent to... `e`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5638361/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Any code that updates the GUI should be run on the thread associated with the GUI. To do so from a different thread, like in your case, you will need to use `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater`:

```
SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // code to update the GUI goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: But what code to update the GUI, a simple call to repaint() ?

Comment: @guillaume yout painting is invoked from Runnable#Thread then repaint() would be wrapped into invokeLater, and nobody knows what's hidden on another methods maybe into invokeAndWait()

Comment: Even if I have `while(cursor < ((rows*cols)-1))
  {   
   timer.start();
   try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         board.repaint(); 
        }
    });
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }    
  }` 
it doesn't work,